# pasar datos de un jtable a otro

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

Buenas gente!! tengo un Jframe con 2 tablas, lo que quiero hacer es pasar datos de una tabla a la otra con un evento mouseclicked, lo cual he logrado, pero solo me carga una columna, es decir si yo hago click con otra cosa de la primera tabla y me la carga en el lugar de la que estaba antes seleccionada ( en la sengunda tabla) les dejo mi codigo a ver si alguien me puede ayudar! muchas gracias!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[[image: introducir la descripción de la i2]magen aquí]]

```
        int FC = tabla1.getSelectedRow();

          cargartabla2();  

    try{

           String codigo,numero,importe;

        if(FC != -1){
            dtm= (DefaultTableModel)tabla1.getModel();
            codigo = tabla1.getValueAt(FC, 0).toString();
            numero=tabla1.getValueAt(FC, 1).toString();
            importe=tabla1.getValueAt(FC, 2).toString();

            dtm= (DefaultTableModel)tabla2.getModel();
            Object fila[] = {codigo,numero,importe};
            dtm.addRow(fila);


        }

    }catch(Exception e ){

    }
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el problema. ¿Que significa `es decir si yo hago click con otra cosa de la primera tabla y me la carga en el lugar de la que estaba antes seleccionada`?

Comment: significa que si yo quiero cargar varios datos de la primera tabla me los cargar en una sola linea de la segunda tabla, como que se sobre escribe en vez de agregarse otra columna y fila abajo

Comment: Listo, actualize mi respuesta. Pasa varias filas al seleccionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**¡¡MODIFCADO!!**

Cree un botón y una nueva operación llamada pasarVariasFilas(). Creas un evento que al presionar el boton se ejecute esta función.

**DATO!!-->** Para que funcione con la selección sin el botón puedes utilizar el evento sobre la tabla mouseReleased().

```
private void pasarVariasFilas (){
        //Esto es nuevo. Recoge todas las filas seleccionadas. 
        int FC[] = tabla1.getSelectedRows();
        DefaultTableModel dtm;
        String codigo,numero,importe;
        //Recorremos todas las filas seleccionadas para cargar los datos.
        for (int i = 0; i < FC.length; i++) {
                //Obtenemos fila por fila.
                int j = FC[i];

                dtm= (DefaultTableModel)tabla1.getModel();
                codigo = tabla1.getValueAt(j, 0)+"";
                numero=tabla1.getValueAt(j, 1)+"";
                importe=tabla1.getValueAt(j, 2)+"";

                if (codigo.equals("null")) {
                    codigo = "";
                }
                if (numero.equals("null")) {
                    numero = "";
                }
                if (importe.equals("null")) {
                    importe = "";
                }


                boolean todoVacio = false;
                if (codigo.isEmpty() &&
                    numero.isEmpty() &&
                    importe.isEmpty()) {
                    todoVacio = true;
                }
                if (!todoVacio) {
                    dtm= (DefaultTableModel)tabla2.getModel();
                    Object fila[] = {codigo,numero,importe};
                    dtm.addRow(fila);
                }

        }

    }
```

Espero que resuelva tu duda.

Comment: sirvio, pero sigue haciendo lo mismo en mi tabla solo carga una linea y no una abajo de otra

Comment: Puedes poner dos capturas de tus tablas? Una donde este recién abierto el programa y otra donde haga eso que comentas. Actualiza tu pregunta y te respondo. Creo que no será problema del código.

Comment: @MaximilianoCorrea O es que quieres pasar varios filas de una tabla a otra?

Comment: quiero pasar varias flias ahora acutalizo y pongo fotos! graciaaas

Comment: @MaximilianoCorrea ho!! Ok. Actualizo mi respuesta.

Comment: ahí actualize mi pregunta con las imagenes

Comment: @MaximilianoCorrea Espero que te este entendiendo bien el problema.  Si no es así lo que quieres por favor en una hoja de excel simula lo que quieres que pase de una a otra tabla. Si tienes el problema de sobreescritura revisa que no estés creando tu tabla dos veces. No se si generaste tu interfaz en netbeans o con código.

Comment: @MaximilianoCorrea Los ejemplos que yo he estado pasandote los cree con tablas hechas desde netbeans. Y no tengo problemas. Si quieres te paso el proyecto para que le eches un ojo.

Comment: seria buenisimo! mi mail es correamaximiliano10@gmail.com

Comment: ya lo pude resolve!! me sale perfecto!! muchas gracias me has hecho el día

Comment: @MaximilianoCorrea Muy bien, me da gusto.